# How to connect an action to a programatically created UIbutton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

Im sure this is probably a very noob question and I apologize in advanced...

This is the first time I have ever created a UIButton programmatically, usually I do it through story board, which easily allows me to connect the button to an action. so my question is, how would I go about connecting this button to an action? (Programmatically of course).

Thanks.

Comment: addTarget:action:forControlEvents:

Comment: If you can't find the method in the class reference, remember to check the class's superclass's as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]
```

`buttonClicked:` is the method that runs when to button is pushed. So if you don't have a method for that you need to create it.

Like this:

```
- (IBAction) buttonClicked: (id)sender {
   NSLog(@"Button pressed");
}
```